# Using custom prev and next buttons (FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

My goal is to have 2 custom buttons to jump 1 week back and forth and another 2 buttons to jump 1 month back and forth. In contrary to the build-in prev and next buttons of FullCalendar, my buttons are supposed not to change with the duration of the view. I am stuck with the syntax here, `calendar.incrementDate( moment.duration(-1, 'week') )` brings up `Uncaught TypeError: e is null` in browser. `moment.js` seems to work fine though. My code:

```
(...)
      customButtons: {
        prevWeek: {
          text: '<',
          click: function() {
            calendar.changeView( 'resourceTimelineWeek' ), //works
            calendar.incrementDate( moment.duration(-1, 'week') ), //error
            alert('clicked the prevWeek button!');
          }
        }
      },
      headerToolbar: {
        center: 'week,month',
        right: 'today prevMonth,prevWeek,nextWeek,nextMonth'
      },
      slotLabelFormat: [
        { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }, // top level of text
        { week: 'W' },
        { weekday: 'short', day: '2-digit' } // lower level of text
      ],
(...)
```

...and two more questions:

1. Is there a way not to use moment.js for this?
2. What is the best way to change the font size / add some custom CSS for a certain custom button (not for all buttons)?

Comment: 1. Yes of course. fullCalendar doesn't require momentJS at all. In fact https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-incrementDate makes clear what the incrementDate function accepts as input. fullCalendar's "Duration" has nothing to do with momentJS's Duration

Comment: 2. This seems like a totally separate issue which deserves a separate question

Comment: 1. Thanks, see my solution below.
2. I posted this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167079/using-custom-css-for-custom-buttons-fullcalendar

Answer (score 2):

With the hint from ADyson I've found the solution:

```
      customButtons: {
        prevWeek: {
          text: '<',
          click: function() {
            calendar.changeView( 'resourceTimelineWeek' );
            calendar.incrementDate( { days: -7 } );
          }
        },
```