# Using custom CSS for custom buttons (FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I have 2 custom buttons for my own fixed `prev` and `next` functions. I like all the buttons how they are but need to make the `<<` and `>>` for those 2 buttons bigger, so I have to change the `FontSize` I guess. What is the best way to do this by preserving the other buttons (including their current `FontSize`) as they are? My code:

```
      customButtons: {
        prevMonth: {
          text: '<<',
          click: function() {
            calendar.changeView( 'resourceTimelineMonth');
            calendar.incrementDate( { days: -31 } );
          }
        },
        nextMonth: {
          text: '>>',
          click: function() {
            calendar.changeView( 'resourceTimelineMonth');
            calendar.incrementDate( { days: 31 } );
          }
        }
      },
      headerToolbar: {
        center: 'week,d14,month',
        right: 'today prevMonth,prev,next,nextMonth'
      },
```

Comment: Probably with the class for those two buttons

Comment: Sure but the issue is that custom buttons share their classes with the other buttons which are not supposed to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.fc .fc-prevMonth-button,
.fc .fc-nextMonth-button {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!